# Get the ID of paragraph inside CKEDITOR 4

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

This is quite simple JavaScript call:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.getData()
```

Returns:

```
<p id="rand_dom_123">Python A B C</p>
<p id="rand_dom_852">PHP A B C D E F</p>
```

However:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.editable().getText()
```

Returns:

```
Python A B C
PHP A B C D E F
```

This is my code:

```
$('.jquery_ckeditor').ckeditor(config);

    CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].on('blur', function() {                
        var html_content = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getSelection().getSelectedText() ;
        alert(html_content);
    });
```

How can I get the `ID` of selected paragraph? Example I can know its paragraph id if I selected `A B C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the document DOM

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].on('blur', function() {                
        var html_content = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].document.$.getElementById('myId') ;
        alert(html_content);
});
```

or you can use the CKEDITOR DOM

```
var element = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( document.getElementById( 'myId' ) );
```

---update---

if you want only the selection than you can enumarate the [range](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range):

```
var ranges = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getSelection().getRanges();

for (var i = 0, len = ranges.length; i < len; ++i) {
    //dig into ranges[i]
}
```

Comment: The problem is I want to get the ID of selected paragraph.

Comment: @BandOfBrothers use ranges

Comment: var html_content = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getSelection().getRanges().createIterator();
    id = html_content.getAttribute('id');
   alert(id); Does not work.

Comment: @BandOfBrothers createIterator() return a collection that you have to iterate with a foreach statement

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated fiddle for you..

http://jsfiddle.net/wfLPg/1/

Jquery:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['my-editor'];
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['my-editor'].editable().getText();
alert(value); // will return both p element texts

var firstPElement = $(editor.editable().$).find('p:eq(0)'); // will select first p element
alert(firstPElement.attr("id")); // will get first p element ID

var secondPElement = $(editor.editable().$).find('p:eq(1)'); // will select second p element
alert(secondPElement.attr("id")); // will get second p element ID
```

Note: `$(editor.editable().$)` :- retrieves a native DOM element for editor editable area for jquery to use as a element

Comment: I am using CKEditor 4

Comment: What is `element` for your case? is the the selected paragraph?